# Maximum and minimum value of a dataset in r

Tags: r, dataset, max, minimum

Hi i am new to r and I have to solve this question  below

Compare the maximum and minimum values within each group (factor level) to their
respective group means. What is the largest absolute diﬀerence between one of your
values and its group mean? What are the chances of obtaining such a value, assuming
the data are normally distributed and centered around the respective group mean with
a standard deviation of 1?

The dataset and frame was generated by

```
  fact<-rep(c("E","F","G","H"),each=12)
  variable2=rnorm(48,10)*(rep(rpois(4,.2),each=12)/8+1)
  ds<-data.frame(fact,variable2)
```

Any help will be appreciated

This is what I have tried

```
library(“plyr”)
ddply(ds,~fact,summarise,maximum=max(variable2),min=min(variable2),mean=mean(variable2))
```

Comment: In addition to what you have tried, what does not work?

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but have you run `library("plyr")` yet?

Comment: Steph thanks that has run the code was trying to use library("ggplot2").  Is there a syntax to use to answer the next bit of the question? What is the largest absolute diﬀerence between one of your values and its group mean? What are the chances of obtaining such a value, assuming the data are normally distributed and centered around the respective group mean with a standard deviation of 1?

Comment: @Diin great, you should now be able to post an update to get rid of the ddply error message. Once you've calculated the mean you should be able to join/merge the summary table against your original dataset to get the difference between the value and the mean.

Comment: @StephLocke can you help me with  the second bit?

Comment: @Diin, the probability bit? Unfortunately this is where my ignorance starts to show! I'd look through something like this ... http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/old/5101/rlook.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there. The `dnorm` function will help you here

```
res <- ddply(ds, ~fact , 
                summarise , 
                maxi = max(variable2) - mean(variable2),
                mini = min(variable2) - mean(variable2) )

res$probmax <- dnorm( res$maxi )
res$probmin <- dnorm( res$mini )
#  fact      maxi      mini    probmax      probmin
#1    E 1.7736537 -1.622157 0.08275571 0.1070311818
#2    F 1.7733593 -2.269254 0.08279894 0.0303883803
#3    G 2.6621257 -3.708242 0.01153470 0.0004120085
#4    H 0.8461922 -1.749625 0.27888407 0.0863339664
```